# Jest SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I am getting the error above when trying to require a file that has import statements. I tried the answers on simular questers to resolve it. It can now read almost all the imports, except for two.

To resolve the first import errors I have made the following files:

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {presets: ['@babel/preset-env']}
```

jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest',
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
  }
};
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-typescript",[
    "next/babel",
    {
      "preset-env": {
        "modules": "commonjs"
      }
    }
  ]   
]
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what I can change so it can succesfully read the last two import modules as well?

Edit: devdependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.0",
    "@rescripts/cli": "0.0.16",
    "@types/deep-equal": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/history": "^4.7.9",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.19",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.11",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.14",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.18",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.16",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.8",
    "@types/reactstrap": "^8.7.2",
    "@types/redux": "^3.6.0",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.9",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.11.3",
    "babel-jest": "^27.3.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap-scss": "^4.6.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.6.2",
    "jest": "^27.3.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react-dev-utils": "^10.2.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "rollup": "^1.32.1",
    "sass": "^1.37.5",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.7",
    "typescript": "^3.9.10"
},
```

Edit: updates the types/jest package

Comment: whats your package.json file look like? specifically the (dev)dependencies you have and the scripts?

Comment: I put the devdependencies in the question as well now